# Android Ask for permission to use location within webview

Tags: java, android, webview, webviewclient, webchromeclient

I have an application that uses a webview and inside the webview is a map, I have got it working to the user automatically find the users location with the following code:

**Manifest file Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**WebView Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    WebViewSettings();

    LoadWebPage(urlString);
}
```

**WebView Settings:**

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void WebViewSettings(){

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.canGoBack();

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientSetup());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    myTimer = new Timer();
    //Start this timer when you create you task
    myTimer.schedule(new loaderTask(), 20000);

}
```

**WebViewClient:**

```
public class WebViewClientSetup extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        // Check to see if there is a progress dialog
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
            SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        isPageLoadedComplete = true;
        View mapHeight = (View) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        int height = mapHeight.getHeight();
        Log.d("map height", "map height" + height);
        // Page is done loading;
        // hide the progress dialog and show the webview
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        AlertDialog();
    }
}
```

**WebChromeClient:**

```
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}
```

So this is working but it automatically gets the users' location without prompting the user if the app can use location services.

Is there a way to add this functionality to the app? Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/@xabaras/android-webview-handling-geolocation-permission-request-cc482f3de210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you need to create the prompt. The `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` function is simply called to let you know the webpage wants the location.

`callback.invoke(origin, true, false);` is the response telling the WebView it's OK to use the location.

The last argument is whether or not to remember this setting. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/GeolocationPermissions.Callback.html

Example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
..... //set up title, message, etc
adb.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        callback.invoke(origin, false, false);
    }
});
adb.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});
adb.show();
```

Comment: Brilliant this is what I'm looking for, thanks for the help been struggling with this for a while