# Android webview , detect if a website is asking for location permission

Tags: java, android, webview, kotlin, geolocation

I am developing a browser in Android webview,
How can I detect if a website is asking for location permission and have custom control to give it or not.

Comment: Don't know if this link would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498523/android-ask-for-permission-to-use-location-within-webview

Answer (score 0):

write below line in onCreate

```
webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
```

write below methode in your class

```
private WebChromeClient mWebChromeCient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);
    }
};
```

[For more detail click tutorials link](https://medium.com/@xabaras/android-webview-handling-geolocation-permission-request-cc482f3de210)